# HTML binding Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript, binding

Boa tarde, Estou precisando de uma ajuda com o Angular 4

tenho o seguinte metodo:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Remedy } from '../remedy/remedy.model'
import { RemedysService } from '../remedys.service'
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'

@Component({
    selector: 'gmr-remedy-details',
    templateUrl: './remedy-details.component.html'
})
export class RemedyDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    remedy: Remedy

    constructor(private remedysService: RemedysService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.remedysService.remedyByMenuId(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
            .subscribe(remedy => this.remedy = remedy)
        console.log(`Parametro : ${this.route.snapshot.params['id']}, Remédio ${this.remedy}`)
    }
}
```

Para ser colocado em um template:

```
<dl class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <dt>Categoria</dt>
    <dd>{{remedy?.des_category}}</dd>
    <dt>Dosagem</dt>
    <dd>{{remedy?.des_dosage}}</dd>
    <dt>Descrição</dt>
    <dd>{{remedy?.des_description}}</dd>
    <a href="#" [routerLink]="['/remedy-register']">
        <h4>Cadastrar novo remédio</h4>
    </a>
</dl>
```

serviço que busca do Web service:

```
remedyByMenuId(id: string): Observable<Remedy> {
    return this.http.get(`${GMR_API}/api/remedys/remedysMenu/${id}`)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(ErrorHandler.handleError)
}
```

Obs: a URL funciona pois utilizo para outros serviços e funciona normalmente.

Porém não consigo o Bind para que os valores apareçam no HTML, e verifico no navegador pela ferramenta de debug o objeto com todos os valores do web service estão sendo retornados normalmente a algo que estou fazendo errado ?

Comment: você pode substituir `.subscribe(remedy => this.remedy = remedy)` por `.subscribe(remedy => { this.remedy = remedy; console.log(this.remedy); })` e me dizer o que é printado no console?

Comment: @mercador tem um log na função init ele volta undefined pq eu pesquisei o remedy e setado antes da execução do on init então vem undefined porém dess jeito q vc colocou ainda não testei vou testar amanhã e posto aqui valeu !

Comment: `undefined` no `ngOnInit` é esperado pois sua requisição pode demorar a retornar algo. Dentro do callback de success no `subscribe` deve vir alguma coisa.

Comment: Opa bom dia tudo bem então o retorno foi um Objeto : log subscribe: [object Object]

Comment: acredito então que para toda referência de `remedy` no seu template, se você usar `*ngIf` deve resolver.

Comment: será ? mas como eu faria no template *ngIf="remedy" ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71811/discussion-between-mercador-and-felipe-sangiorge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como estava:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.remedysService.remedyByMenuId(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
            .subscribe(remedy => this.remedy = remedy)
        console.log(`Parametro : ${this.route.snapshot.params['id']}, Remédio ${this.remedy}`)
    }
}
```

Resolução :

```
  this.remedysService.remedyByMenuId(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
    .subscribe(response => {
          this.remedy = {des_name : response[0].des_name}
          console.log(this.remedy)
    })
```

A verdade é que o retorno estava vindo como array, depois de deixar essa parte de lado aprofundar meus conhecimentos e voltar a analizar percebi que retornava em forma de array no indice [0] ou seja bastava pegar os retornos desse indice popular em um objeto e fazer o bind desse objeto.